# How to monitor firestore and execute multiple games at the same time by app engine?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How can I monitor firestore and execute multiple games at the same time by app engine or other Google cloud service? (Due to the 9-minute limit of Cloud Functions, I can't using Cloud Function) :((

I wrote the code to onsnapshot the collection path in Firestore by referring to the official documents. The code example is as follows:

```
def hello_firestore(last_match_key): 
    print('%s start!!!' % last_match_key)
    # TODO execute game. For about 13 minutes
    asyncio.run(Game_main(last_match_key).waitingForAllMatch())
    print('%s done!' % last_match_key)

# onsnapshot
def CustomizeOnSnap(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            last_match_key = u'{}'.format(change.document.id)
            return hello_firestore(last_match_key)
        else:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.collection(u"PlayAndScore").on_snapshot(CustomizeOnSnap)
```

For this code, I can successfully use onsnapshot to execute the function of my game.

However, since the first game a is still executing, it turns out that I can only run one game at a time, and cannot execute multiple sets at the same time (I can monitor the second game, but I will not automatically start second game untill the end of the first game). How can I solve the problem that I can't play multiple games at the same time?

Could someone give me a few solution with this question ? It's been bothering me for two months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use **[Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview)** instead of Cloud Functions.  You can have multiple Cloud Tasks running simultaneously and you can set the waiting time for up to 24 hours for manual scaling if you use manual scaling.

Another way that may be work depending on your use-case, is using [traffic splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/splitting-traffic) on App Engine.

A thought that might be a far shot, would be generating endpoints for each game you want from within the main code. 
Just like the basic Flask example:

```
@app.route('/greeting/<name>')
def give_greeting(name):
    return 'Hello, {0}!'.format(name)
```

This way you'll get separate "games" running for each user if that's anyhow what you're trying to achieve.

However, from your description of the use case, I'd go with Cloud Tasks.

Comment: I'm sorry to be back so late. Thank you for your answer!

About 10 days ago, I really used threading and traffic splitting to solve this problem!!! I really hope I could see your comment early.  :((((

After reading your answers and official documents, I will learn cloud tasks carefully next! Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Hope you find the ideas useful for the future.